# Rails find - order by presence of Paperclip attachment then record creation datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am building a gallery index of Items in which some Items have photos and others do not.

I would like to grab all of the Items (or a subset with will_paginate) and sort them first by the items with a photo (attached via Paperclip) and then by the record creation date.

I need a binary "has attachment" type status for the first part. Do I need to make some additional model attributes and use paperclip's callbacks to set the status of a binary column? Or is there a better way?

I would prefer to do this sorting at the DB level since we will be using will_paginate to cycle through blocks of records.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we are suing SQLite in dev and postgres in production (and may switch production soon) CONV() wasn't available.

We went with doing a comparison in the ORDER BY clause to create the binary value needed.

```
ORDER BY (photo_file_name IS NULL) ASC, created_at DESC
```

This appears to be supported by all our DBs and accomplishes the intended goal.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to create an additional field, instead convert the filename to boolean on the fly with CONV (I'm making an assumption you are running this on MySQL - but equivalent functions are available on other RDBMS).

```
ORDER BY CONV(photo_file_name,2,2) DESC, created_at
```

Technically, CONV is a function to convert numbers between different bases, but it accepts string input. It will return 0 if a value is present in the photo_file_name column and NULL if NULL input.

[MySQL CONV Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv)

Comment: Yes, I had thought about that,but then the items with photos are actually sorted by filename unless they all have the same filename.

Comment: And you actually want them sorted by created date, photos first?

Comment: Yes. I want to give priorities to items with photos, but then sort by creation date. So all items with photos are clumped together, sorted by creation date, and then all items without photos, again sorted by creation date.

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your clarification.

Comment: Thanks. We are using sqlite on dev boxes so that function wasn't available. But you inspired a solution... doing a comparison in the order by clause to make the necessary binary.